# Password_verify says incorrect password

Tags: php

I am coding a Login in PHP the thing is it says the password is incorrect even though I know it is correct.

I assign my variables using this

```
$password = trim($_POST['password']);
$user_password = $user['password']; //Hashed password from database
$salt = '-45dfeHK/__yu349@-/klF21-1_\/4JkUP/4';
$hashed_password = hash(sha256, $password . $salt);
```

I check the password through

```
if(password_verify($user_password, $hashed_password)){}
```

but it returns false but if I use

```
if($user_password == $hashed_password){}
```

it works fine.

Edit:

```
$password = trim($_POST['password']);
$user_password = $userdata['password'];
if(password_verify($password, $user_password)){}
```

Comment: password_verify expects the users password to be unhashed https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$user_password` was created with `hash()` it wont work, it needs to be created with `crypt()` or preferably `password_hash`. If your 'stuck' with your current `hash()` created passwords, you simply cant use `password_verify` but i would encourage you to switch to this system asap.

password_verify expects the users password to be unhashed https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

```
$user_password=trim($_POST['password'])

if(password_verify($user_password, $user['password'])){}
```

it does all the rehashing for you.

Comment: How does it know which hash and what salt?

Comment: the salt is in the string stored in the db, as is the hash algorithm. specific details: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: I use `$hashed_password = hash(sha256, $password . $salt);` to hash it right now, so switch it to `$password = crypt($password.$salt);` ? This seems less secure since it's not being hashed?

Comment: well you simply cant use `password_verify` then. you should switch to `password_hash` wich hashes for you. and `crypt` does indeed hash

Comment: @Dan `password_hash` is the better solution above hash and crypt. You really should just switch (if your user database isn't already filled of hash() passwords).